# Typescript not correctly inferring type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
class A {
    readonly is_prop: boolean;
    constructor(is_prop: boolean) {
        this.is_prop = is_prop;
    }
}

class B {
    readonly my_prop: boolean;
    constructor(my_prop: boolean) {
        this.my_prop = my_prop;
    }
}

type A1 = A & {is_prop: true};
type A2 = A & {is_prop: false};

type C = A1 | A2 | B;

const a: A = new A(true);
const b: A = new A(false);
const c: B = new B(true);

const e: A1 | null = a.is_prop ? a : null;
```

In the above example, why is the assignment for `e` giving error? Why is TS not inferring that `is_prop` will be true

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQE4FMwBMD2AdiAJ7QCWEA%20gA7p7UBc0ARnniNgQNwprCEQALugCuwQXnQAKCjTqMWbDmAIBKRLzRpBACwoA6WbXrQAvOSrHqPLQF8k9pKEgwAQhq1ZchEtAC2xHL0TKzsnDZ8AsJiEtIBQQqhymoeWtp6EPrxVmb%20gVYRqPaOgsTUmHAAjLnwAGSIRvJM0Zi2PKXlcABMNdD1CI3B0ABmYCAQrTxIHRUAwjXVAD7d0MuuU-wEQtBgTPDmBJgA7nBSLao8m9vMe7mHJ7BSo%20OYF05R0MBM7gfH0K5nUSvDYfTB7JbQAgiEAgXJgQyWeTQAD8O2gTChMK4QA)

Comment: Intersection types in typescript behave as function overloading as far as I know. So saying `A & {is_prop: true};` equals to a type that has both `is_prop : boolean` and `is_prop: true`. They aren't actually unified, which is what I believe you want which would be `type A1 = Omit<A, 'is_prop'> & { is_prop:true};`

Comment: That still gives error on assignment

Comment: It's something along the lines of that. I am not entirely sure of the correct utility that's why I didn't put it as an answer. The point is as far as I know you can't achieve this by simple intersection. You will need to use [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html)

Answer (score 1):

The error is because `a` is of type `A`:

```
const a: A = new A(true);
```

In the ternary, you check that `is_prop` is `true`, but the variable `a` is still of type `A`. The *property* has been narrowed to `true`, but `a` hasn't changed types. As an example, this code would be valid based on your narrowing:

```
const trueVal: true | null = a.is_prop ? a.is_prop : null
```

If you want to be able to narrow the type of `a`, you need to say that it can be one of several types by stating that it's a union:

```
const a: A1|A2 = new A(true);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQE4FMwBMD2AdiAJ7QCWEA+gA7p7UBc0ARnniNgQNwprCEQALugCuwQXnQAKCjTqMWbDmAIBKRLzRpBACwoA6WbXrQAvOSrHqPLQF8k9pIOLVMcAIxm40AGSIj8kzCIpi2PM6ucABMXvB+CAH0TABmYCAQoTxI-ARC0GBMsO4APrAx5gSYAO5wUsGYqjw5eZiFnsXQBCIgIF5ghpby0AD8+dBMXT1ZAPSz+SCCmOgEYIJkAG6YENngUNAAQhpaWLiEJBZySYrsnDZafALB4pIyg1esNyrqyPfaehADS7ULyJayaaCOLRzISrMjAaAAW0wujwOGgulWGGRImWMEg6J0bhEBDIhAY4Jha3hwBOi1eQKYH2UaiY+wAKqJMMV9gAxNIZI6-LGCHEETrVA70qyNcGQtBzCKYADmIjA6Bw4Io7M5UlUQX+FgOHJCgt+WBFywJBlBd1Q9nsiqNnK8h3ioKCnLCThcbl5-Lc5ld-jeClS6UySGyjxYnkD+hp2Dp9RlzUELAA8ugAHLdEDuVnGrmTXrmZjuQFWEYx8adXNZVMscrimr7OqclPR5iZnM9KIFznFYteZhRAbakK6qsjmvFnhAA) with some more alternatives.

Comment: This is the true explanation of the actual and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because of this line of code

```
type A1 = A & {is_prop: true}; //for class a, is_prop is boolean
```

boolean is not a subset of true, so you can't assign class A to type A1:

you could try this:

```
type A1 = A & {is_prop: boolean};
```

or this:

```
const e: A1 | null = a.is_prop ? a as A1: null;
```

Comment: Please don't suggest unsafe castings when there are safe alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

That's because that `true` doesn't equal `boolean` type

And I don't think you need to declare type of the variables `a b c` again

They can be directly implicitly declared through the following [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

```js
class A<T = boolean> {
  readonly is_prop: T extends boolean ? T : never;
  constructor(is_prop: T extends boolean ? T : never) {
    this.is_prop = is_prop;
  }
}

class B {
  readonly my_prop: boolean;
  constructor(my_prop: boolean) {
    this.my_prop = my_prop;
  }
}

type A1 = A & { is_prop: true };
type A2 = A & { is_prop: false };

type C = A1 | A2 | B;

const a = new A(true);
const b = new A(false);
const c = new B(true);

const e: A1 | null = a.is_prop ? a : null;
```

In this way, you don't have to declare type `A1 A2 C` and declare type `A1 | null` to `e`, and then you can get more simplified code like that

```js
class A<T = boolean> {
  readonly is_prop: T extends boolean ? T : never;
  constructor(is_prop: T extends boolean ? T : never) {
    this.is_prop = is_prop;
  }
}

class B {
  readonly my_prop: boolean;
  constructor(my_prop: boolean) {
    this.my_prop = my_prop;
  }
}

const a = new A(true);
const b = new A(false);
const c = new B(true);

const e = a.is_prop ? a : null;
```